# DocumentDb requires 64bit

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have this code:

```
            var list = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<MatchActivityDataModel>(_collection.SelfLink, sql, new FeedOptions() { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = false });
            var result =  list.ToList();
```

where sql is SqlQuerySpec object. It results in error :"Partition routing information cannot be extracted from the query when running in a 32-bit process. To complete your query and avoid this exception, ensure that your host process is 64-bit."

I know how to fix it by running it in 64bit process. However, I'm hosting my app in Azure, and hosting it with 64 forces me to upgrade to more expensive tier (I don't make money from this app, so I would rather keep it on lowest tier possible). Is there a way to make it work in 32bit environment? My collection is not partitioned.

Comment: Here is a git issue about this error: https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/140

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET SDK 1.11.3 has the fix for that. You can create a single partition collection in a 32-bit mode in that version.

Starting 1.11.4, we also support creating a partitioned collection or performing a cross partition query in 32-bit mode.

32-bit mode is a bit less performant but if you have a limitation of upgrading to 64-bit, it should be fine.

Please let me know if that resolves your issue after upgrading to the latest SDK.